# Android and picasso loading listview

Tags: java, android, listview, picasso

I m actually trying to load different images with Picasso(http://square.github.io/picasso/) in a listview using a simple code and it doesnt work.

In fact, I need to load remote pictures, and display them in a simple listview, without using fragments (because I dont need it at all)

I dont know what's going wrong... Can you help ?

This is my adapter code :

```
package id2tel.surikatsante.view.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import id2tel.surikatsante.R;
import id2tel.surikatsante.view.rowItem.AnomalieRowItem;

/**
 * Cette classe herite de BaseAdapter
 *
 * @author Vincent Danti
 * @version 4.0
 * @since 1.0
 */
public class AnomalieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<AnomalieRowItem> rowItems;

    public AnomalieAdapter(Context context, List<AnomalieRowItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitre;
        ImageView img;
        ImageView imgCheck;
        LinearLayout layout;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_anomalies, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitre = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.titre);

            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);

            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img);

            holder.imgCheck = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final AnomalieRowItem rowItem = (AnomalieRowItem) getItem(position);

        holder.txtTitre.setText(rowItem.getLibelle());

        if (rowItem.getM_Anomalie().getM_icon() != null) {

            Picasso.with(context).load(rowItem.getM_Anomalie().getM_icon()).placeholder(R.drawable.waiting).into(holder.img);
        } else {
            holder.img.setBackgroundColor(0xffED695A);
        }


        if (rowItem.isChecked()) {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(0xffdddddd);
            holder.imgCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(0xffefefef);
            holder.imgCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    /**
     * @param position est une position gps (hérite de toto)
     * @return object
     */
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

}
```

I always pass in the .error() method of Picasso....

thanks for advance

Comment: Does this method return a URL : `rowItem.getM_Anomalie().getM_icon()` ? If yes, did you check if it is correctly formatted ?  And did you enable the Internet persmission in your manifest ?

Comment: Yes for the url, yes for the formate and yes for the permission. The fact is that it work with Ion library (but soo slooow) and that I use Picasso in another activity and it works great. The remote URL works too in a browser

Comment: It seems that it loads only the first image in fact